# How to convert the following foreach nested loop to LINQ?

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, linq, foreach

Code:

```
foreach (var item in items.Children)
{
    RadTreeViewItem parent1 = new RadTreeViewItem();
    parent1.Header = NodeHeader(item.Path, item.Name, SelectedPath, ProjectData);
    parent1.Tag = item;
    foreach (var child in item.Children)
    {
        RadTreeViewItem children = new RadTreeViewItem();
        children.Header = NodeHeader(child.Path, child.Name, SelectedPath, ProjectData);
        children.Tag = child;
        parent1.Items.Add(children);
    }
    Parent.Items.Add(parent1);
}
```

items.Children and item.Children  are `ObservableCollection<>`

parent1.Header and children.Header are `HeaderedItemsControl.Header`

parent1.Tag and children.Tag are `FrameworkElement.Tag`

How to convert the above foreach nested loop to LINQ ?

Comment: Instead of creating items in code, you should be using WPF data binding to bind your data to the RadTreeeView control. It's much easier and it already supports hierarchical binding

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LINQ... Language INtegrated (and here's the key bit) **Query**.

What you are doing is not a query. Leave it with the `foreach` loops; it is fine, it is clear, it is obvious.

In particular, the `.Items.Add` methods on the various collections is not really something you can trivially reproduce in LINQ. You can probably do it, but it will be ugly and hard to maintain. What you have is fine. If you want to change it for change's sake, maybe:

```
RadTreeViewItem parent1 = new RadTreeViewItem {
    Header = NodeHeader(item.Path, item.Name, SelectedPath, ProjectData),
    Tag = item
};
foreach (var child in item.Children)
{
    parent1.Items.Add(new RadTreeViewItem {
        Header = NodeHeader(child.Path, child.Name, SelectedPath, ProjectData),
        Tag = child
    });
}
Parent.Items.Add(parent1);
```

Not exactly an improvement, IMO.